# GlobalAlloc explanation

Tags: c++, winapi

```
(char*)GlobalAlloc(GPTR, len + 1);
```

This is the line of code in question, which I'm using from a tutorial.  I'm reading from an `EDITTEXT`.  I'd mostly like to know where `GPTR` came from, and what it's for.  It hasn't been defined anywhere else in the code.

I've got a basic understanding of the rest of the line, but [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa366574%28VS.85%29.aspx)'s explanation isn't quite clear.  They say this:

```
HGLOBAL WINAPI GlobalAlloc(
  __in  UINT uFlags,
  __in  SIZE_T dwBytes
);
```

Could someone explain in plain English where `GPTR` is from, what it's for, and how it relates to `__in UINT uFlags`?  I know it's an `unsigned int` but then the knowing stops.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Refer [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa366574%28VS.85%29.aspx)

GPTR 0x0040  Combines GMEM_FIXED and GMEM_ZEROINIT.

As you can see, it is just a bit pattern (0x0040) and can be combined with other permissible flags

Answer (score 3):

GPTR is athe combination of GMEM_FIXED and GMEM_ZEROINIT(OR).

**uFlags**
The memory allocation attributes. If zero is specified, the default is GMEM_FIXED. This parameter can be one or more of the following values, except for the incompatible combinations that are specifically noted.

Value Meaning
    **GHND**    0x0042 Combines GMEM_MOVEABLE and GMEM_ZEROINIT.
    **GMEM_FIXED**    0x0000 Allocates fixed memory. The return value is a pointer.
    **GMEM_MOVEABLE**    0x0002 Allocates movable memory. Memory blocks are never moved in physical memory, but they can be    moved within the default heap. This value cannot be combined with GMEM_FIXED.
    **GMEM_ZEROINIT**    0x0040 Initializes memory contents to zero.
    **GPTR**    0x0040 Combines GMEM FIXED and GMEM_ZEROINIT.